# Rails showing files list and not running app

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger, ubuntu-10.10

I followed this tutorial: http://railsapps.github.com/tutorial-rails-mongoid-devise.html

Running nginx via proxy on port 8000. You can see it here.

Why is it listing the files in the /public dir? Also, if I try to go to any of the devise uris, it shows the Nginx 404, and not the rails 404...could this be a passenger issue?

I'm new to server admin/rails. So it could be an nginx issue OR rails config. Any advice for a rails student/zombie?

Part of my problem is that I don't know much about error logs. How do I check nginx/apache/rails logs for errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kevin,

It looks like Apache maybe misconfigured.  Upon clicking one of the links in the file list it tried to redirect it to,

```
Proxy Error

The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request GET /error.log.

Reason: DNS lookup failure for: rails.pixelcraftwebdesign.com:8000error.log
```

You can add rails.pixelcraftwebdesigns.com to /etc/hosts but it looks like a trailing / might be missing on your proxy_pass directive.

Comment: That's just an apache thing. Try pixelcraftwebdesign.com:8000.

Comment: ^^IT SHOULD WORK CORRECTLY FROM THAT ADDRESS!^^